# Is there a proof assistant (or an embedding) for the (co)end calculus?

Tags: type-theory, software-request, category-theory, type-rule

[*A Higher-Order Calculus for Categories*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44755-5_11) describes a system where you can conveniently perform manipulations with categories, functors, Yoneda embeddings etc. An example of the rules is: $$\frac{\Gamma , X {:} \mathcal C^{\mathsf{op}}, Y {:} \mathcal C \vdash E : \mathcal D, \quad \mathcal D\textsf{ complete}, \quad \mathcal C\textsf{ small}}{\Gamma \vdash \int_{X, Y} E : \mathcal D}$$

Is there an actual implementation for this system? Embedding into an existing proof assistant also counts. Internet searches don't seem to yield anything.

Comment: Of interest: "A Higher-Order Calculus for Categories" ([pdf](https://www.brics.dk/RS/01/27/BRICS-RS-01-27.pdf))

Comment: If this answers your question let me know and I will post as an answer. "Category Theory" by Alexander Katovsky ([pdf](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.656.9368&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). ([Code page](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Category2.html))

Comment: @GuyCoder I think that formalizes category theory inside Isabelle/HOL. What I'm expecting is something like Isabelle/Cat, which directly implements the manipulations as typing rules (instead of lemmata and theorems). Nonetheless I think your link is quite cool, and I'll look into it.

Comment: @Trebor It looks like the authors describe an implementation of the calculus in Isabelle/Pure in the first paper cited by Guy Coder. I would be interested in taking a look at the implementation if it is still available somewhere.

Comment: I've started implementing it in agda-categories, but had to pause because I got too busy with my day job as a prof... I'd warmly welcome PRs that would continue that work.

Comment: @JacquesCarette Can you provide a pointer? I might attempt to contribute (or maybe just play around).

Comment: @JacquesCarette Do you know anything about the availability of the Isabelle source code of the authors? How far did they get with their own formalization?

Comment: @Trebor agda-categories is at https://github.com/agda/agda-categories.  I was systematically working my way through the (co)end is my (co)friend book and adding it all directly to the library. No, I don't know about the Isabelle parts.